# Smallest positive number to trigger carry out

Tags: cpu-architecture, twos-complement, base-conversion

I'm following a course on Computer Architecture and I have the following exercise:

> What is the smallest positive decimal number that should be added to -20 so that a carry-out is triggered (in 2 complement's notation)?

I solved this exercise, but I'm not sure of my results. So I found this:

First convert -20 to 2 complements binary notation. This gives -20 = 11101100. Now add 000101000 to trigger a carry out. Which is equivalent to 20.

Would that be correct?

Comment: Yup, looks right to me.  [This tutorial on Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) teaches it very well, IMO.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! That is correct!

Adding `-20` to `20` will give you `0` as a result with a carry-out `1`. If you choose any positive number smaller than `20` it won't generate a carry-out and the result will be a negative number. If you choose any positive number larger than `20` it will generate a carry-out with a positive result. So `20` is the answer you are looking for.

If you really want to go into the binary detail, you can go step-by-step:

1. We are looking for a number that will be added to `-20` and will generate a carry-out, let's represent it with `x`, `y` will be the result and `c` will be the carry-out.

```
      11101100
    + xxxxxxxx
      --------
     cyyyyyyyy
```

2. We are looking for `c = 1` and we know that `X is positive` so its most significant bit is `0`

```
      11101100
    + 0xxxxxxx
      --------
     1yyyyyyyy
```

3. Now we can clearly see that the only way that we can get a carry-out from bit 7 is by getting a carry-in from bit 6. So `y[6] = 0`.

```
      11101100
    + 0xxxxxxx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

4. There are two ways we can generate a carry on bit `6`. Either `x[6]` is one. Or there was a carry-in from bit 5. We want to minimize `x`, so we should choose `x = 0` with a carry-in from bit `5`.

```
      11101100
    + 00xxxxxx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

5. The same applies to bit `5`. We can choose between `x[5] = 1` or a carry-in from bit `4`. We should go for carry-in from bit `4`, since we have to minimize `x`.

```
      11101100
    + 000xxxxx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

6. Now we don't have any other option other than set `x[4] = 1` because if `x[4] = 0` there will be no carry being propagated to higher bits.

```
      11101100
    + 0001xxxx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

7. And we are back on the same as 4. `x[3] = 0` to minimize `x`.

```
      11101100
    + 00010xxx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

8. Finally we got to the last `1` on the operand. It is our last chance to generate a carry. If we choose `x = 0` there will be no carry out. Our only option is `x = 1`.

```
      11101100
    + 000101xx
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

9. Last two bits of `x` should be `0`, because once again we are minimizing `x`.

```
      11101100
    + 00010100
      --------
     10yyyyyyy
```

10. And the result is... (with carry indicated)

```
      11111
      11101100
    + 00010100
      --------
     100000000
```

Ta-da!

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very clear :)